# Qt QGraphicsScene does not fitInView() with scrollbars

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qgraphicsview

[QGraphicsView::fitInView()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) seems to ignore the presence of scrollbars, that apparently are overlaid. (It also uses a hardcoded 2 pixel margin.)

There is a related bug report (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-1047) stating that calling fitInView() twice would resolve the problem.

In my case, it does not. Only triggering it twice manually fits regarding the scrollbars. This does not work:

```
void myGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  if( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton ) {
    QGraphicsItem* clicked = scene()->itemAt( mapToScene( event->pos() ) );
    qDebug() << clicked << clicked->boundingRect();
    fitInView( clicked, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    fitInView( clicked, Qt::KeepAspectRatio); // doesn't work for me
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    return;
  }
}
```

Is there another workaround?

Qt 4.8.1 with MSVC2010

Answer (score 6):

Calling fitInView() twice does work, but you have to let Qt process its events between the two calls.

This also means you end up redrawing the graphicsview twice.

To avoid this, what I do is:

1. Disable updates
2. Call fitInView
3. Call QApplication::processEvents()
4. Call fitInView again
5. Enable updates

In your code it would look like this:

```
bool updateState = updatesEnabled();
setUpdatesEnabled(false);
fitInView(clicked, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
fitInView(clicked, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
setUpdatesEnabled(updateState);
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause could be this (at least it looks like it is in the bug report): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42331 - please vote on it on the qt bug tracker to up its priority.

In short, fitInView has hardcoded margins and this can cause all kinds of havoc - the least of which is that now you lose a few pixels of display area and might also force unnecessary rescaling.  It can cause runaway resizing and weird instabilities such as what the QTBUG-1047 bug submitter described.

You can fix the problem by reimplementing fitInView, based on the existing implementation but removing it's ridiculous margins. An example of that is available here in python, based on the original C++ version:

https://github.com/nevion/pyqimageview/blob/master/qimageview/widget.py#L276

Let me know if it fixes your problem!  That way we can close out that since-2007 bug too.